# How do I run and edit this github code?

Tags: html, frontend, ejs

I am new to developing but I want to experiment with making changes to this code my friend made for a site we are working on. This is the github link:

https://github.com/415DomSmith/ADA_Map

I've opened html files with chrome before to view them but that doesnt seem to work here. Opening views/landing.ejs with chrome doesnt render the whole site.

Here is a screenshot of the main folder contents:

[main folder contents screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uHTR.jpg)

So my question is what program can I use to render and make edits to the code? Can brackets do it? I've tried with no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. cd ${the root path of the project}
2. npm install
3. node app.js
4. visit localhost:3000 in the browser.

According to your description, I think you are new of nodejs and express.
If you want to understand it thoroughly, you must study below.

1. npm package
2. nodejs
3. express